# Linux - Count in the number of files that have more than a n lines

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

How can I count the number of files that have more than a n lines that are under a directory (including the files that are under it's subdirectories)?
I was looking at `find` as it allows recursive search in the directory tree

Comment: find | while read filename | wc -l | test      Hope that's enough hint for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

count the number of files more than 100 lines

```
$ find path/to/dir -type f -exec wc -l {} + | awk '$1>100{c++} END{print c?c-1:c}'
```

replace 100 with your number.

Answer (score 1):

One simple example is piping while on find:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
n=4
find . -type f | \
    while read -r file; do
        [[ $(wc -l < $file) -lt $n ]] || echo $file;
    done
```

You can add the output in an array and format it if needed.

Comment: Thanks this works but a command instead of a script seems more simple

Comment: You can make any short script a one line command with semi-colons.  e.g. find . -type f | while read -r file;do [[ $(wc -l < $file) -lt 4 ]] || echo $file;done

Comment: Nice, I didn't know

Answer (score 1):

You can use find -exec to run wc -l and then pipe the output into awk to process the entries and so:

```
find . -type f -exec wc -l '{}' \; | awk -v cnt="11" '$1>cnt { print }'
```

Run wc -l on each file found and then use awk and pass the "n" value as a variable cnt. The first space delimited field is then compared to cnt for each line (in this case 11) and then if it is greater, the line is printed.

Comment: Thanks, this worked too after adding a `| wc -l` at the end

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` to run `wc` on each file. Pipe the output to `head` to remove the "total" line and awk to filter out the small files.

```
find . -type f -exec wc -l {} + \
| head -n-1 \
| awk -v n=40000 '($1>n){print}'
```